# Automatically Show Comment Form in Facebook Comments Plugin

Tags: facebook, addition, comments

So I want to use the Facebook Comment Plugin but on my plugin it show "Add a Comment" in the corner so any time a user wants to post something they have to click that first. Is there any way to remove that link and just have the comment box/form show automatically?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!